# Conditional in Head to detect channel

Tags: channel-entries, ee6

I have an issue with detecting the channel of an entry so I can apply schema for different types of entries based on the channel:

```
<head>
{exp:channel:entries limit="1"}
  {if channel == "blog_post"}
  my schema here... 
  {if:elseif channel == "recipe"}
  my schema here... 
  {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
</head>
```

When I put out the channel in the comments I'll see another channel and not the blog post or recipe channel that it's been posted on in the admin. I used `{segment_1}` with success since the URL structure is `/recipe/{url_title}` and `/blog/{url_title}` but I'm SOL if I create a custom URL. Why wouldn't `{channel}` be accurate and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: theoretically, this should work. What version of EE are you using?

Comment: 6, I added my answer when I figured it out. I'm working on a client site so I assume there's some screwy configs or maybe it's just EE weirdness. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. I needed to specify the channels at the top of the loop.

```
<head>
{exp:channel:entries limit="1" channel="recipe|blog_post" }
  {if channel_short_name == "blog_post"}
  my schema here... 
  {if:elseif channel_short_name == "recipe"}
  my schema here... 
  {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
</head>
```

I would expect `exp:channel:entries` to get the accurate info and I would not need to specify a scope of channels to search so I can use the specific fields for each channel. I'll have to remember to add the channel to the parameter list if I want to add more schema per channel content.